# Nodejs - Ejecutar función que se encuentra dentro de socket.io

Tags: javascript, nodejs, socket.io

Estoy buscando la forma de ejecutar una función que se encuentra dentro de socket io usando Nodejs:

```
ejecutar("envio este mensaje");
 io.on("connection", function(socket){
  var ejecutar = function(msj){
    console.log(msj);
  }
 })
```

No he podido hacerlo, incluso he buscado usar bind para intentar pasarle algún parámetro, pero no domino mucho el tema. Les agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Comment: El la consola deberías ver un error, ya que la función `ejecutar` no esta definida por fuera de la función `function(socket)`. Puede que [este articulo te ayude a entender más sobre `scopes y closures`](https://medium.com/@sergiodxa/definiendo-conceptos-closure-y-scope-en-javascript-9081f1e113e6#.upffe2ow8)

Answer (score 0):

También soy nuevo en todo esto de Nodejs pero creo que te falta ejecutar el soket es muy vaga la idea que me das con tu código y tu explicación. Prueba con esto...

```
   io.on('connection', function(socket){
        socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
               console.log('message: ' + msg);
        });
   });
```

Comment: Estimado no deseo hacer un chat (en ningún lugar menciono el recibir un evento del cliente y luego ejecutar un mensaje). Lo que menciono es: Ejecutar una función que se encuentra dentro de la función correspondiente a socket.io (en este caso, he definido la función ejecutar dentro de socket.io) ESA función deseo ejecutar desde a fuera.

Answer (score 0):

solo tienes declarar la función de la siguiente forma:

```
ejecutar("envio este mensaje");
 io.on("connection", function(socket){
 this.ejecutar = function(msj){
 console.log(msj);
 }
})
```

Comment: No reconoce la función "ejecutar" ¿La has probado?